# JOIN / UNION SELECT all rows from two tables with different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am trying to join or union the results of two differently structured tables, order them by a their common pubdate column, but get an error message:

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE published='1' AND image!='' AND featured='1'
JOIN
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE published='1'
ORDER BY pubdate DESC
```

How can I edit my query so that I can run my fetch array and retrieve the corresponding rows afterwards (the rows to be fetched is then decided on another common row that both tables share)?

Comment: Can you show us a few rows of sample table data and it's expected result?

Comment: Thanks all for your help so far, I have edited the code above to provide more detail about the data and output i would like to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

Since you not provided sample data, we can't suggest you correct way what and how to use, but I noticed that:

With [**JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) you have incorrect syntax. Should be like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

If you want to use [**UNION**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) - order of columns and number of columns should match in both tables, so you have to provide column names in both tables, in following:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Coln
FROM tbl1

UNION

SELECT Col1, Col2, Coln
FROM tbl2
```

Comment: Tables used by OP have different number of columns. So the UNION ALL you show here above will work only if you **remove** from the SELECT list one or more column from the table having more columns. This means the result of your UNION ALL will have **less info** than the two original tables. The other approach is to **add** NULL/literals/functions/whatever you want to the table having less columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION ALL` tables with a different number of columns by adding the missing columns in the select list. I mean, suppose you have:

```
SQL> create table one ( c1 integer , c2 integer, c3 integer ) ;
SQL> create table two ( c1 integer , c2 integer ) ;
```

The following `UNION ALL` won't work:

```
SQL> select * from one union all select * from two ;
[mysqld-5.5.27]The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

But this one is ok:

```
SQL> select * from one union all select *, null from two ;
```

Note we did add NULL for the missing (c3) column on table `two`. You can add whatever you want...

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas I tend to agree but is a matter of personal preference. I did it for brevity's sake. I think OP got the answer he was looking for...